# Access IsolatedStorage of an existing application

Tags: c#, .net, isolatedstorage

I have to develop a Windows application to backup files which are created by another application. Theses files are saved in the IsolatedStorage(GetUserStoreForApplication)

How can i access the IsolatedStorage of the second application ?

Thanks !

Comment: you must get the current working directory of the app and can have access to that folder using administrator account

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the [`Storeadm.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezabwsbk.aspx) process and redirect the output of the `/list` switch.